# How to list the slowest JUnit tests in a multi-module Maven build

Tags: testing, junit, maven, hudson, jenkins

How can I list the slowest JUnit tests in a multi-module Maven build?

This should be accross all modules.

A Hudson/Jenkins solution could also do.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Disclaimer: I truly apologize for my bash solution, although it works and fits in one line :-). If you are impatient, go to the bottom.

First we need to find all `TEST-*.xml` files produced by `maven-surefire-plugin`. Run this after `mvn test` in the root directory of your project to discover test results in all submodules:

```
$ find . -iname "TEST-*.xml"
```

Fortunately the format of these files is pretty straightforward, a simple `grep` and we have what we need:

```
$ grep -h "<testcase" `find . -iname "TEST-*.xml"`
```

Now some `sed` magic to extract invocation time, test case class and method name:

```
$ sed 's/<testcase time="\(.*\)" classname="\(.*\)" name="\(.*\)".*/\1\t\2.\3/'
```

There's nothing more left just to sort the result and display longest running tests:

```
$ sort -rn | head
```

## Promised *one-liner*:

```
$ grep -h "<testcase" `find . -iname "TEST-*.xml"` | sed 's/<testcase time="\(.*\)" classname="\(.*\)" name="\(.*\)".*/\1\t\2.\3/' | sort -rn | head
```

Amazingly, the results look reasonable (Activiti 5.1 multi-module code-base taken as an example):

```
3.029   org.activiti.examples.variables.jpa.JPAVariableTest.testStoreJPAEntityAsVariable
2.904   org.activiti.engine.test.forms.FormsTest.testTaskFormPropertyDefaultsAndFormRendering
1.594   org.activiti.engine.test.api.mgmt.ManagementServiceTest.testGetJobExceptionStacktrace
1.114   org.activiti.examples.variables.jpa.JPAVariableTest.testUpdateJPAEntityValues
1.006   org.activiti.engine.test.db.EngineRebootProcessDefinitionCacheTest.testStartProcessInstanceByIdAfterReboot
0       org.activiti.engine.test.pvm.PvmVariablesTest.testVariables
0       org.activiti.engine.test.pvm.PvmScopeWaitStateTest.testWaitStateScope
0       org.activiti.engine.test.pvm.PvmScopesAndConcurrencyTest.testConcurrentPathsGoingIntoScope
0       org.activiti.engine.test.pvm.PvmEventTest.testNestedActivitiesEventsOnTransitionEvents
0       org.activiti.engine.test.pvm.PvmEventTest.testEmbeddedSubProcessEvents
```

Comment: In my case, `time` and `name` attributes are inverted. The one-liner becomes:

`grep -h "<testcase" `find . -iname "TEST-*.xml"` | sed 's/<testcase name="\(.*\)" classname="\(.*\)" time="\(.*\)".*/\3\t\2.\1/' | sort -rn | head`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, letting me know where to look for such information. For me though, one liner didn't list the time, this worked for me: grep -h "<testcase" `find . -iname "TEST-*.xml"`| perl -ne 'print "$1\t$2\t$3\n" if /name=\"(\S+)\"\s+classname=\"(\S+)\"\s+time=\"(\S+)\"/ && $3 > 30' | sort -g -k3 -r | head -n100  for test cases taking longer than 30 seconds