# List jUnit Tests That Were Run

Tags: java, html, junit

Is there a way to get a list of the jUnit tests that were run for the purpose of including that list in a report?

Rather than copying the 80 unit tests I ran, I was hoping to output it as html or a csv that I could then turn into a figure for my report.

Extra points if the pass/fail status of each test were included.

Comment: Have a look at this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094410.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you run them, but if you're using maven, then the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) produces a report for you.

If you're using ant, see [How do I use Ant to create HTML test reports?](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_6)